# Dominated convergence theorem for finitely additive measures

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

Consider a metric space $\mathfrak X$, and consider
$$
rba(\mathfrak X):= \{\mu: \mathcal B(\mathfrak X)\to \mathbb R; \mu(\emptyset)=0, \text{finite, regular and finitely additive}\},
$$
where $\mathcal B(\mathfrak X)$ denote the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathfrak X$. Then for an element $\mu\in rba(\mathfrak X)$ it is possible to construct an integral, as explained in Yosida's book 'Functional Analysis' for instance.

My question is: for such $\mu$ does a standard dominated convergence theorem hold? Shouldn't it be the case, which extra assumptions are needed?

Comment: Usually, DCT is equivalent to $\sigma$-additive